# Query for all keys having a particular value in a nested json document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am looking for a mongosh query to get all keys in a nested json that have values in a particular range or equal to a particular value.

Consider the example json below

```
{
  Root : 
  {
    model_year :
    {
      Car1 : 2018,
      Car2 : 2019,
      Car3 : 2018
    },
   fuel_capacity : 
   {
     Car1 : 500,
     Car2 : 450,
     Car3 : 300
   }
  }
}
```

I want to query this json to get all car keys with

1. fuel_capacity greater than 400
2. model_year equal to 2018

I am completely new to mongodb so want to know if this is kind of query is possible?
If yes then what would be the performance for this query for billions of records.

Comment: Why is the data modeled this way? If you are often going to be querying it in the manner described here in the question, then you will make your life much easier by adjusting the schema for the documents. The query is trivial if the documents are constructed differently, but is pretty convoluted (and probably poorly performing) if the documents are stored like this

Comment: This is just sample data to explain my requirement. Actual data is much more complex which I cannot share here. I want to know if this type of query is possible in mongodb irrespective of my data model.

Comment: It is "possible" but in the worst kind of way. It will be large, hard to write, difficult to reason about, and will perform very poorly as it cannot use indexes. Also to clarify what you're looking for here, do you want the conditions `AND`ed together (so only `Car1` should be returned)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         model_year: { $objectToArray: "$Root.model_year" },
         fuel_capacity: { $objectToArray: "$Root.fuel_capacity" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         fuel_capacity: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$fuel_capacity",
               cond: { $gt: ["$$this.v", 400] }
            }
         },
         model_year: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$model_year",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this.v", 2018] }
            }
         },
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         model_year: { $map: { input: "$model_year", in: "$$this.k" } },
         fuel_capacity: { $map: { input: "$fuel_capacity", in: "$$this.k" } }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uq7gwQPTRGG)

But as already mentioned in the comment, you should really review the data model.
Compare the query if you have better model:

```
db.collection.insertOne({
   Root: [
      { model_year: 2018, fuel_capacity: 500, model: "Car1" },
      { model_year: 2019, fuel_capacity: 450, model: "Car2" },
      { model_year: 2018, fuel_capacity: 300, model: "Car3" },
   ]
})

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         cars: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Root",
               cond: {
                  $or: [
                     { $gt: ["$$this.fuel_capacity", 400] },
                     { $eq: ["$$this.model_year", 2018] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

or even this:

```
db.collection.insertMany([
   { model_year: 2018, fuel_capacity: 500, model: "Car1" },
   { model_year: 2019, fuel_capacity: 450, model: "Car2" },
   { model_year: 2018, fuel_capacity: 300, model: "Car3" }
])

db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         fuel_capacity: { $gt: 400 },
         model_year: 400
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Kudos for posting an answer, but I don't think the first aggregation on their current data model is correct. I took OP's question to mean they want entries where the two conditions are `AND`ed together which would mean just `Car1` should be returned. But I could be wrong and OP should clarify. In any case, you then have `OR` logic in your second solution but `AND` logic in your third so they should probably be consistent. Also minor typo in the `model_year` of the third one. TOTALLY agree about the data model change, so much simpler. Current one can't use indexes at all anyway

Comment: @user20042973 yes, I saw the same when I created the alternative data model, the requirement is not clear. Anyway, TO should get an idea how it works.